# Importing data from Excel to MySQL database using SQLyog

Tags: mysql, excel, data-warehouse, sqlyog

Is there a way to automate importing of data from Excel/csv to MySQL database using SQLyog so that it automatically updates every time?

Answer (score 0):

use `Database -> Import -> Import External Data`

Automatically each time what happens though ? It may be easier using `LOAD DATA` mysql command on a cronjob.

For an "update" by CSV check out

http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-use-mysql-fast-load-data-for-updates-1753.html

```
Step 1: Use LOAD DATA to import the entire input file into a temporary table and update primary key id's for any existing records we already have

Step 2: Use SELECT INTO OUTFILE to write all records we couldn't find an id for (new records) into a temporary text file

Step 3: Use LOAD DATA to add all new records (from step 2) into the target table

Step 4: Use a single UPDATE query, to update all records that match an existing primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlyog is a standalone application and can't automate the importing process.

You can create a cronjob for LOAD DATA INFILE command to your server.